# Either Replace or Substitute in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to replace a character, "-", with ":" in all of our product names. It needs to work for the entire column A, not just a single cell, AND there are multiple "-"'s in some of the products, but I just need the first in each product. For example, we have product Spuhr-SP-3016 and product AI-0497. I need to replace only the first - in the Spuhr one and the - in the AI one. And again, this will need to be for thousands of products, not just a single cell but a range (A2:A3000, or all of column A if range doesn't work). Is there a formula using either Replace or Substitute?  All instructions I found demonstrate for one cell only instead of a range.

Comment: You would put the formula in one cell with a relative reference to A2, then copy/drag the formula down the data set.  The A2 would change to A3 then A4 and so on.

Comment: Looks to me you'll need VBA since the functions you referenced only hit one cell at a time. Using VBA, you'd iterate over a range and apply the function to each cell OR, you'd use VBA to do a Find/Replace over a range of cells.

Comment: Put this in B2: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",":",1)` and copy/drag it down the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `FIND` function in combination with `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

The `FIND` gets the first position of a "-" and you get the `LEFT` of that -1 so it ignores the "-".  Then get the length, `LEN`, minus the same position from the first `FIND` without the -1 to get the rest of the string. In between both functions just add the ".".

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)&"."&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))
```

Comment: no need to parse, the Substitute has a fourth criterion that allows the user to define which gets replaced: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",":",1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner That seems like a much easier option, lol. Looks like I did one of these http://devhumor.com/content/uploads/images/February2017/rust.png